# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'

Tags: python

I have a few dataframes from an API set as variables shown in the list of data. When I tried to perform some functions the error shows:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'

```
data = ['dataA','dataB','dataC','dataD']

for i in data:
     exec('{} = pd.DataFrame()'.format(i))

for i in data:
    ma = 6

    smaString = "SMA" + str(ma)

    data[smaString] = data.iloc[:,3].rolling(window = ma).mean()

    data = data.iloc[ma:]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You are not creating dataframe from your list. `exec('{} = pd.DataFrame()'.format(i))` this is very bad, try finding how to convert list to dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the error pops up because 'data' is not a dataframe but a list. 'iloc' or 'loc' functions cannot be used on a list.

In your question, you have shown the error message to have 'loc' whereas you have used 'iloc' in your code. These are two different things:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Also, it's unclear what you are trying to achieve from this code here.